# Inserting multiple generated student records from an HTML5 form into MySQL database

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I want to insert multiple student records that I have generated in an array into my terminal_assessment table in my database. after entering all the generated student records when I post only the last student records are inserted. below is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('login.php');

echo "<form method='post' action=''>";

//fetching all JSS 1 students from students' table
$student_sql = "SELECT * FROM `sch`.student where classAdmitted = 'jss1' ORDER BY firstName";

//creating table columns for all student records heading
echo "<table><tr><th>S/No.</th><th>Admission No</th><th>Full Names</th><th>Current Class</th><th>Subject</th><th>CA1</th><th>CA2</th><th>Exam</th><th>Total</th></tr>";

//looping through all the student present in a class and their subjects for exam recording
foreach($conn->query($student_sql) as $row1)
{
    $fullName=strtoupper($row1['firstName']." ".$row1['middleName']." ".$row1['surName']);
    $stud_id = $row1['studentID'];

    echo "<tr><td></td><td>".$row1['studentID']."</td><td>".$fullName."</td><td>".$row1['classAdmitted']."</td><td class='scol'><select name='subCode'><option value='agric'>Agric Science</option><option value='bio'>Biology</option><option value='bus'>Business Study</option><option value='crk'>Christian Religious Study</option><option value='econs'>Economics</option><option value='eng'>English Language</option><option value='fst'>Food Science</option><option value='intech'>Introductory Technology</option><option value='maths'>Mathematics</option><option value='soc'>Social Study</option></select></td><td class='scol'><input name='ca1' type='number' class='sub' value='0'></td><td class='scol'><input name='ca2' type='number' class='sub' value='0'></td><td class='scol'><input type='number' name='ca3' class='sub' value='0'></td><td class='scol'><input type='number' name='ca4' class='sub' value='0'></td></tr>";
}
    echo "</tr></table>";
    echo "<div id='btmbar'>";
    printf('Total Number of Students: %d', $conn->affected_rows);
    echo "<br><input id='btn1' type='submit' name='add' value='Get TOTAL'><input id='btn2' type='submit' value='Submit Student Records' name='submit'>";
    echo "</div></div></form>";

$student_ta_id = $sess = $className = $term = $subNames = $ca1 = $ca2 = $ca3 = $ca4 = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $student_ta_id = "$stud_id"."$session"."$className"."$term"."$subjects";
    $term = $_POST['term'];
    $student_ID = $row1['studentID'];
    $className = $row1['classAdmitted'];
    $subjects = $_POST['subCode'];
    $ca1 = $_POST['ca1'];
    $ca2 = $_POST['ca2'];
    $ca3 = $_POST['ca3'];
    $ca4 = $ca1 + $ca2 + $ca3;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `sch`.terminal_assessment (student_ta_id, session, className, term, subjectNames, ca1, ca2, exam, total) VALUES('$student_ta_id', '$session', '$className', '$term', '$subjects', '$ca1', '$ca2', '$ca3', '$ca4')";
$insert = $conn->query($sql);

if($insert === True)
{
    echo "Record inserted successfully". "<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error Unable to Insert Record".die($conn->error);
}

}
    $conn->close();
?>
```

[Preview of the HTML5 format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pgGM.png)

Comment: One at a time usually

Comment: This is really too broad a question, but if you show us the HTML for your page someone may be able to help you

Comment: You question is unclear. However, if you have an array of student data you should be able to loop through it adding a new record each time.

Comment: so take a one at a time approach this is basic cms code google up 
use something like ajax 
a broad answer to a broad question

Comment: I see you've accepted a bad answer and ignored a good one, so I have downvoted the question. Please consider replying to the answer from Roger Tiong RTdev (if only because it is polite to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic :)

1. For HTML form body make your select name and input name like this:

   ```
   subCode[]
   ca1[]
   ca2[]
   ca3[]
   ```
2. In php

   ```
       if(isset($_POST['subCode'], $_POST['cal1'], $_POST['cal2'], $_POST['cal3'])){
           $sc = $_POST['subCode'];
           $c1 = $_POST['cal2'];
           $c2 = $_POST['cal2'];
           $c3 = $_POST['cal3'];
   ```

   `$keys = array_keys($sc);
       $data = array();

       foreach($keys as $k => $v){

          $data[$v] = array($sc[$v], $c1[$v], $c2[$v], $c3[$v]);

       }

       $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name(subCode, cal1, cal2, cal3) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';

       if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){

           $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $subCode, $cal1, $cal2, $cal3);

           foreach ($data as $v) {

               $subCode = $v[0];
               $cal1 = $v[1];
               $cal2 = $v[2];
               $cal3 = $v[3];

               $stmt->execute();

               if($stmt->insert_id <= 0){
                   trigger_error('Insert fail. Error: ' . $stmt->error);
                   break;
               }

           }
           $stmt->close();
           $conn->close();

       }else{
           trigger_error('Prepare fail. Error: ' . $stmt->error);
       }
   }`

Comment: Thanks Roger Tiong

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is that in the form you generates, for each control for each student, you give the same name; thus creates a conflict: the lastly created controls with the same name are the one taken into account, that's why only the last is inserted. Also, I think the way you get the id of the student is not correct. I would suggest you do like this:

You should add a number to the name of each control for each control per line (per student). You should also store the StudentID and the classAdmitted in hidden fields

```
//looping through all the student present in a class and their subjects for exam recording
//this variable will be incremented for each line that you display; you then can use it to identify the values related to a specific line. e.g: subCode_1 would identify the selected major on the line 1 while subCode_2, the selected one on line 2 
$line_id = 1; 
foreach($conn->query($student_sql) as $row1){
    $fullName=strtoupper($row1['firstName']." ".$row1['middleName']." ".$row1['surName']);
    $stud_id = $row1['studentID'];
    echo "<tr><td></td><td>".$row1['studentID']."</td><td>".$fullName."</td><td>".$row1['classAdmitted']."</td><td class='scol'><select name='subCode_$line_id'><option value='agric'>Agric Science</option><option value='bio'>Biology</option><option value='bus'>Business Study</option><option value='crk'>Christian Religious Study</option><option value='econs'>Economics</option><option value='eng'>English Language</option><option value='fst'>Food Science</option><option value='intech'>Introductory Technology</option><option value='maths'>Mathematics</option><option value='soc'>Social Study</option></select></td><td class='scol'><input name='ca1_$line_id' type='number' class='sub' value='0'></td><td class='scol'><input name='ca2_$line_id' type='number' class='sub' value='0'></td><td class='scol'><input type='number' name='ca3_$line_id' class='sub' value='0'></td><td class='scol'><input type='number' name='ca4_$line_id' class='sub' value='0'></td></tr><input name='StudentID_$line_id' value='".$row1['studentID']."' type='hidden'/><input name='classAdmitted_$line_id' value='".$row1['studentID']."' type='hidden'/>";
    $line_id++;
}
//Here you add a hidden field that contains the number of lines
echo "<input name='line_count' value='$line_id' type='hidden'/>";

echo "</tr></table>";
echo "<div id='btmbar'>";
printf('Total Number of Students: %d', $conn->affected_rows);
echo "<br><input id='btn1' type='submit' name='add' value='Get TOTAL'><input id='btn2' type='submit' value='Submit Student Records' name='submit'>";
echo "</div></div></form>";
```

After that, you get the information about the number of lines stored in the hidden field, do a for loop and get all the values of the form per line and store them...the second part of your code should look like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $line_count = $_POST['line_count'];
    for($i=1; $i<$line_count;$i++){

        $term = $_POST['term'];
        $session = $_POST['session'];
        $student_ID = $_POST['studentID_'.$id];
        $className = $_POST['classAdmitted_'.$id];
        $subjects = $_POST['subCode_'.$id];
        $ca1 = $_POST['ca1_'.$id];
        $ca2 = $_POST['ca2_'.$id];
        $ca3 = $_POST['ca3_'.$id];
        $ca4 = $ca1 + $ca2 + $ca3;
      $student_ta_id="$stud_id"."$session"."$className"."$term"."$subjects";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `sch`.terminal_assessment (student_ta_id, session, className, term, subjectNames, ca1, ca2, exam, total) VALUES('$student_ta_id', '$session', '$className', '$term', '$subjects', '$ca1', '$ca2', '$ca3', '$ca4')";
        $insert = $conn->query($sql);
        if($insert === True){
            echo "Record inserted successfully". "<br>";
        }else{
            echo "Error Unable to Insert Record".die($conn->error);
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks.. Your code worked for me. but i just have to do some little changes in order to solve d problem i had. I will get back 2u as soon as i encountered other challenges. Also, am glad u LOVE JESUS too

Comment: great..feel free...just hope i will be able to deal with it :)

Comment: This answer appears to have a serious SQL injection vulnerability in it. Please be careful about answering SQL questions here, since we do not wish to make poor security practices worse by actively promoting them.

Comment: could you please tell more about that vulnerability? how could it be avoided?